# ProducerTemplate is there supposed to be only one instance

Tags: spring, apache-camel

We are using Spring and Camel in our web application.  In one of our controllers we are using the ProducerTemplate to send a message on a route and now I want to add another controller that will send a message down a separate route.  I an trying to understand if we are only suppose to have one ProducerTemplate for the whole application?

I ask this because I got a little confused after reading [this](http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from the link you gave:

> You are not meant to create a ProducerTemplate for each message invocation; you are meant to create a single instance on startup and keep it around.
>
> Also when you have finished using the ProducerTemplate you should call the stop() method to close down all the resources it has been using.

So, in a typical Web application you would **not** create a `ProducerTemplate` for every request like:

```
ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
```

This is considered a bad practice, for obvious reasons.

Instead the endpoint should be injected, e.g. by using the [`@EndpointInject` annotation](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/EndpointInject.html)

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "file:{{file.inbox}}")
private ProducerTemplate inbox;
```

as described [here](http://camel.apache.org/bean-injection.html).

Answer (score 2):

In general, make sure you don't create a new ProducerTemplate for each message being processed.  That being said, creating a few of them in different routes/beans/processors is fine as well...just cache them for subsequent message requests.